# hierarchy structure in mongodb with jongo in java?

Tags: java, mongodb, jongo

I have a java project with the following structure:

An abstract class `Event` and other 3 sub classes `EventA`, `EventB` and `EventB`.

The code is something like this.

```
public abstract class Event {

    @MongoId
    @MongoObjectId
    private String id;

    private Place place;
    private Person person;

    public Event() { }

    //more code
}

public class EventA extends Event {

    private OtherObject other;

    public EventA() { }
    //more code
}

//more classes
```

In a service class, I have to query for a List , so...

**How can I do to model the correct Mongo-hierarchy/inheritance in java?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution, maybe it could be useful for someone with the same problem:

So, you can declare every subclass over the abstract class

```
@JsonTypeInfo(use= JsonTypeInfo.Id.CLASS, property="_class")
@JsonSubTypes({
    @JsonSubTypes.Type(value = EventA.class),
    @JsonSubTypes.Type(value = EventB.class),
    @JsonSubTypes.Type(value = EventC.class)
}) 
public abstract class Event(){
   //code
}
```